# Python - Importing from source root results in "No module named '<source root>'"

Tags: python, import, importerror, directory-structure, modulenotfounderror

Investigating how I should be structuring my projects and tests I cloned into the [nose repository](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose.git) and found the same problem I had been having.

This is how the project is structured:

```
nose <----- repository root
    nose <- source root
        __main__.py
        __init__.py
        core.py
        [...]
    unit_tests
    .gitignore
    [...]
```

If I run

```
python nose/__main__.py
```

I get

```
File "/home/daniel/Projects/nose/nose/__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from nose.core import run_exit
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nose'
```

I realize there is probably a fix involving `PYTHONPATH` but being fairly new to Python I feel like there must be a way for a project to work "out of the box" without having to tinker with any system variables.

For context this entire investigation started as I found my tests failing because the imports in my non-test code would fail (my project's structure is the same as Nose's). For example:

```
from package import module
from package.subpackage import module
```

Would result in the following error when running tests:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package'
```

The tests would run fine if I changed my imports to be like nose's. For example:

```
from project.package import module
from project.package.subpackage import module
```

But then I'd run into the aforementioned error when trying to run the program normally.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'
```

Comment: The root directory when doing your tests and when running your app must be different. Can you print the first item of `sys.path` when running your tests and when running your app to see if there is a difference ?

Comment: @SpaceBurger you are correct, when running my tests the path is the tests root (project/test) and when running my app the path is my sources root(project/project)

Comment: Then the most direct solution would be to add your source's directory in front of `sys.path` (with a simple `sys.path.insert(abs_path_to_sources_root))`. That way you don't have to change your imports in your sources or tests. However this must be run before any tests begins ; maybe there is an option of your test module that can do that automatically and you don't even have to write code. Another solution would be to put your tests alongside your code, but I don't know if it's recommended. Depends what your testing module is as well.